# update and change Power BI report which has incremental refresh feature

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence, powerbi-datasource

Hello Power BI pros,

We have running Power BI reports on Power BI online portal, they get data from API calls and have incremental refresh feature we are happy with the historical data we still have even after deletion from source. Right now we want to update the reports with new data points and new calls possibilities plus some new charts using the the Power BI desktop app, but we know this may cause us to lose the incremental refresh and the historical data (1 year old) we already have.

Is there any trick or solution we can use to avoid loosing the historical data and the incremental refresh feature?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Create a new report and use the dataset from the original report as a data source for the new one.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov thanks for your comment. we decided to use any kind of database to store historical data instead of counting only on Power BI incremental refresh, but we still have to find a way to access or collect the data we saved in the online reports using the incremental refresh and save it to the new database! do you know a way to do that?

Comment: You can connect to the XMLA endpoint and export the data. You can do that even with PowerShell, e.g. https://sqlitybi.com/how-to-export-data-from-power-bi-using-xmla-endpoints/